# Magento 2: How to show order total in 2 different currencies in checkout page of onepage checkout

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, checkout-page, order-totals

I have 2 different currencies in my site with USD as base currency and EURO as secondary currency. My client wants to show the total in these 2 currencies in the checkout page. So in all other places price will be show in USD but in checkout page the total should be show in 2 currencies like

Order Total : USD 100 
              EUR 150

Can anybody direct me which template I have to override and how I can show the total in 2 currencies. I have already set up the 2 currencies in the back end but not sure how I can show both of them in the front end. Any help will be much appreciated. I am using Magento 2.2.5 community edition.

Answer (score 0):

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/grand-total.html actually shows the grand total if that helps :).